# LinkedHashSet not removing

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I am experiencing a weird behaviour and I am not sure why. I try to remove an element from a `LinkedHashSet` and it is not removed.

My class Document has defined:

```
protected Set<Author> authors = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Then Author equals when both `id` and `role` are equal::

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);
    hash = 53 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.role);
    System.out.println("Calling hashcode: " + hash);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("Calling equals");
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("1");
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("2");
    final Author other = (Author) obj;
    if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("3");
    if (!Objects.equals(this.role, other.role)) {
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("4");
    return true;
}
```

Then the code that removes with some debug printing:

```
public void removeAuthor(Author author) {
    System.out.println(">removeAuthor [" + author.hashCode() + "]: " + author);
    if (document.getAuthors() != null) {
        System.out.println("[" + document.getAuthors().size() + "] Authors BEFORE:");
        document.getAuthors().forEach((pp) -> {
            System.out.println("[" + pp.hashCode() + "] " + pp);
        });
    }

    if (document != null) {
        if (document.getAuthors() != null) {
            document.getAuthors().remove(author);
        }
    }

    if (document.getAuthors() != null) {
        System.out.println("[" + document.getAuthors().size() + "] Authors AFTER:");
        document.getAuthors().forEach((pp) -> {
            System.out.println("[" + pp.hashCode() + "] " + pp);
        });
    }
}
```

And this prints the following (I add my comments):

```
// Call to hashCode() to print the author that will be removed
    Calling hashcode: 400605768   
// Author that will be removed
    >removeAuthor [400605768]: Author{id=self, name=Self Centre, forename=null, familyName=null, role=Writer} 
// List before calling remove, it gives 2 authors
    [2] Authors BEFORE:
    Calling hashcode: -1820871746
    [-1820871746] Author{id=self, name=Self Centre, forename=null, familyName=null, role=Researcher}
    Calling hashcode: 400605768
    [400605768] Author{id=self, name=Self Centre, forename=null, familyName=null, role=Writer}
// This hashCode call is probably done by remove(). As it can be seen, the object to be removed *is* on the Set
    Calling hashcode: 400605768
// List after calling remove, it gives again 2 authors
    [2] Authors AFTER:
    Calling hashcode: -1820871746
    [-1820871746] Author{id=self, name=Self Centre, forename=null, familyName=null, role=Researcher}
    Calling hashcode: 400605768
    [400605768] Author{id=self, name=Self Centre, forename=null, familyName=null, role=Writer}
    Calling hashcode: -1820871746
```

I am use to using Sets in general. It might be a stupid mistake, but I cannot find where it is. Also, compareTo or other methods do not seem to be used to test equality.

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: What you have when you call contains method. `document.getAuthors().contains(author)` ?

Comment: What type is Author.role? If its a custom class has it also implemented equals?

Comment: Author role is a String, same as id. But equals does not seem to be called

Comment: `System.out.println("contains " + document.getAuthors().contains(author));` returns `contains false`

Comment: The issue is that this is part of a more complex environment... I am using JSF to add and remove elements in the set and I can remove data successfully. But then I call a Controller method via ajax to save the set in the database. It is saved correctly. And just when it returns from saving is when I cannot remove the set. To me, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSF, since the hashCode is the same and it is basic Set operation on a memory variable

Comment: Sorry, the contains() actually makes it print two things: `Calling hashcode: 400605768
contains false`, so the hashCode() is called

Comment: What the data from `author` you want to remove.... If `equals` not called mean that the hasCode are not same.

Comment: @ÉricRoberge but you can see in the log.. It is the same!  `400605768`  that is why I am seriously confused

Comment: For what I have seen in my logs, `equals` is only called on `add()`, not on remove

Comment: I think (but I might be wrong) that `equals()` is called on `remove` only when there's a colision (more than 2 elements have the same hash code)

Comment: Now, regarding your problem. The code is OK, and the element should be removed from the set. The problem is somewhere else. For example, you mentioned you are serializing/deserializing your entities, and you also mentioned a database. Are you using an ORM? Which one? If not, how are you mapping your entities to the database? I suspect your problem has to do with proxies, which are used by several ORMs. If your entity is a proxy, this part of your `equals` method `if (getClass() != obj.getClass())` will return `false`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner well, I am not sure that is right in this setup, in my example I can remove successfully elements from the Set (before executing the JSF ajax call) and equals is not called. The hashCodes() are exaclty the same as after calling the JSF ajax, but then they are not removed

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner the ajax call only calls an update query that deletes all existing relations and inserts the ones coming from data from the set. I do not re-read again `document` or change the object in memory at all, not using any ORM. I only call the method, use the set in read-only operations, tell JSF to render the form again and that is it. `equals` is never called and the objects keep the same hashCodes as before. You can see in the logs it is exactly the same number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved the mistery, thanks to debugging. It is an obvious mistake from Ajax usage. When creating the `LinkedHashSet`, the elements are added in a hash table in an index based on their `hashCode`. Sometimes, Ajax JSF operations can change the `role` of objects in memory, which makes them change their hashes. However, **the position in the hash table where they were originally inserted is not changed at all**! Therefore, you have now an element with a specific hash that you want to remove, the element does exist in your Set (as seen, the hashes were identical) but when the actual code attempts to remove the element from `table[ (table.length-1) & hash ]` it is never found, because it is not in that position - it was originally added with another hash value. This solves the mistery and it is totally logical.

Comment: Actually, it is not that serious. It is just that some ajax methods allow changing roles (amongst other attributes) which is totally sensible, and they happen to be part of the key. So set elements should be removed and inserted again when such change happens.

Comment: Under control now. Thanks! = )